# How do I detect if my Node.js script is excuting from NPM installation or not?

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a CLI script that can be installed by users through NPM or by a native package created from [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg). Is there a way I can detect in the script itself at runtime if the user is using it through NPM or not? Does NPM set any type of environment variable or anything?

Comment: npm does add some variables to `process.env`, but a globally installed package is set up in such a way that it executes the package script directly via node

Comment: What `process.env` variables are set? I assume I could just check for one of those.

Comment: `NPM_CLI_JS` is one, lots other starting with `npm_`. But like I said, if your package is meant to be installed globally (using `npm i -g`), you won't see those variables.

Comment: Ah, I see the difference.